# Is there a way to automatically detect if a variable is multiple categorical or continuous

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, continuous-data

If your dataset is big, say you have thousands of variables. Some variables are multiple categorical and some are continuous. Question is, how do you know if a variable is continuous vs multiple categorical (say 50 categories)? Is there any algorithm that can classify this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35826912/170339